# How to set jquery-ui draggable revert to true if after a validation i decide to move the element back?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for a way to trigger the event from revert status if something doesnt validate, for example if the element doenst exist it will create it from another list, but if it already exists it should go to else and returns the element to its original position:

```
$( "#catalog ul" ).droppable({
        tolerance: 'fit',
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            //check if already exists
            if($(this).find("#"+$(ui.draggable).attr("id")).length==0){
                $( "<li id="+$(ui.draggable).attr("id")+"></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this )
                .draggable({
                    revert: 'invalid',
                    stop: function(){
                        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
                    }
                }).droppable({
                    greedy: true,
                    tolerance: 'touch',
                    drop: function(event,ui){
                        ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
                    }
                });
            }else{
                //want to make the object go back by setting true to revert
                return false;
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Nevermind, i found it after reviewing the whole code i just have to put ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true) inside the else. Wow was trying this for almost a day, lol.

Just answering my own question if someone doenst pay attention like me and get the same problem.

Comment: kenji, the correct way to answer your own question (which is perfectly fine on SO!) is to literally do that: Post an answer below, then two days later (SO makes you wait), make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks Kenji, this indeed works:

```
ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
```

I also struggled with this for a morning until finding your post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.droppable({
     greedy: true
}
```

this option is necessarily needs too