# How do I revert back to original position when you hit 'cancel' upon delete confirmation (JQUERY UI draggable & droppable )?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

jsfiddle.net/L9tba27k/

See how my draggable image sits on top of the trash bin when you hit cancel? How do I fix that? It only reverts back to the original position if you drag the pic a little bit outside of the trash bin.

Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Why don't you just set `revert: true` in the draggable options?  http://jsfiddle.net/L9tba27k/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is pretty well unguessable. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960306/how-to-set-jquery-ui-draggable-revert-to-true-if-after-a-validation-i-decide-to).

```
 $('.trash').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
     drop: function (event, ui) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
            ui.draggable.remove();
        } else {
            ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true); 
        }
    }
});
```

An no, you haven't gone cross-eyed, `.draggable` really does appear twice.

**[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9tba27k/3/)**

Comment: Ingenious in its simplicity! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
function doConfirm() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable();
    $('.trash').droppable({
        accept: '.draggable',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $('.draggable').draggable("option", "revert", doConfirm);
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/L9tba27k/2/)

You can put your `.remove()` code within `doConfirm()` to remove the element upon confirmation.

Comment: Hey man, I checked your fiddle. For some reason, after I hit cancel and drag the pic again, even outside of the trash, it keeps asking me if I want to delete it or not. I think your code is bugged